# Does electric current occurs because of magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I'm wondering if electric current (flow of electrons) occurs because of magnetic field, or because of the brushes?

Will an electric current still occur just with a spinning armature and a magnetic field and without those brushes?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes the electrons will move without the brushes.  Let's suppose that when the armature is perpendicular to the magnetic filed (and rotating) that the electrons are moving from right to left in the top part of the armature.  They will subsequently moving from left to right in the bottom part of the armature.  The problem comes when the armature goes through the parallel of the magnetic filed, the currents will go to zero and then reverse in the armature.  So from the reference frame of the armature, the current will oscillate back and forth with the frequency of the rotation.  The function of the brushes is to move the electrons through the circuit.  So as the armature rotates, the legs switch between the legs of the armature.  So the electrons which are always moving to the left for the piece of the armature at the top, will always go through the circuit in the same direction.